# How to assign numerical values to JRadiobuttons in Java and use them as multipliers?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I want to make a simple calculator using text fields and radio buttons. I already have 3 text fields and a "calculate" button with action listener working. But now I want to add 3 new radio buttons grouped, with values such as 1, 10 and 1000 as multipliers excluding each others (I want them to multiply the final result, but I want to use only the `JButton` as action taker not the radio buttons).

The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("calculate!");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        double x, y, z, result;

        x= Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
        y= Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText());
        z= Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText());
        result = x * y * z;

        textField_3.setText(Double.toString(your result is));   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JRadioButtons with a ButtonGroup, like:

```
final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

final JRadioButton btn1 = new JRadioButton("1");
final JRadioButton btn10 = new JRadioButton("10");
final JRadioButton btn1000 = new JRadioButton("1000");
group.add(btn1);
group.add(btn10);
group.add(btn1000);

...

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            double x, y, z, result;

                x= Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                y= Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText());
                z= Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText());
                result = x * y * z;
                if (btn10.isSelected()) result *= 10;
                if (btn1000.isSelected()) result *= 1000;

                textField_3.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion!